# Passing a value based on button click in CakePHP2

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I have a list of objects generated via the Elements folder in my CakePHP project.

I'm trying to implement a detail button where when the button is clicked, a new component appears with the specified details, where the component is used by all objects.

`index.ctp` where the list of objects will be displayed, in addition to a hidden details component

`object.ctp` element that has basic information of the object and a "details" button that is rendered by `index.ctp` multiple times with value `object` being passed into it.

```php
// index.ctp
echo $this->element(
    'details',
    array(
         'object' => $object
    )
);
```

I have a jQuery function in `index.ctp` that allows me to retrieve the `data-id` value I set in the `object.ctp` file that logs the appropriate object ID.

```js
// index.ctp
$(document).on("click", ".detail-button", function(e) {
    slider.slideReveal("show", function() {});
    var $button = $(this);
    var object_id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log(object_id);
});
```

How do I go about passing the appropriate `$object` value in `$this->element(...)` based on which object component is clicked?

Comment: Hi, you're saying *I have an AJAX function*, but the code below doesn't seem to have any AJAX. If the question is how to communicate back to the server, and if you use jQuery (which looks like the case here), then it's a matter of a simple `jQuery.ajax` call. Does this sound about right? Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Sorry about that, you are correct, there is no AJAX, but just jQuery in the snippet I provided. I have a segment `this->element('element_name', array('data' => $data))`. I'm trying to pass a value to the `$data` variable.

Comment: so that value for the `$data` is supposed to come from AJAX, correct? If that's the case, then roughly speaking you need to have your AJAX talk to a controller method which will take the object from the AJAX request (as a JSON, maybe) and pass it to the element, render the element into a variable, take the resulting code and respond with that code, which you can then insert into your page using Javascript. Sounds about right?